# Automate the Boring Stuff, Chapter 5 Practice Project

Tags: python

I was having a little trouble with the second function in this program, so I took a few hints from what I could find on it online (at reddit). I don't quite like it but can't seem to think of a better way right now.

"Write a function named addToInventory(inventory, addedItems), where the inventory parameter is a dictionary representing the player’s inventory (like in the previous project) and the addedItems parameter is a list like dragonLoot. The addToInventory() function should return a dictionary that represents the updated inventory. Note that the addedItems list can contain multiples of the same item. "

Here's what I have:

```
stuff = {'rope': 1, 'torch': 6, 'gold coin': 42, 'dagger': 1, 'arrow': 12}

def displayInventory(inventory):    # This function is correct.
    print("Inventory:")
    item_total = 0
    for k, v in inventory.items():
        item_total = item_total + v
        print(str(stuff.get(k, 0)) + ' ' + k)

    print("Total number of items: " + str(item_total))

displayInventory(stuff)

def addToInventory(inventory, addedItems):
    for i in range(len(addedItems)):
        inv.setdefault(addedItems[i], 0)
        inv[addedItems[i]] = inv[addedItems[i]] + 1

    return inv

inv = {'gold coin': 42, 'rope': 1}
dragonLoot = ['gold coin', 'dagger', 'gold coin', 'gold coin', 'ruby']
inv = addToInventory(inv, dragonLoot)
displayInventory(inv)
```

Current output:

Inventory:
1 rope
42 gold coin
6 torch
12 arrow
1 dagger
Total number of items: 62
Inventory:
1 rope
42 gold coin
1 dagger
0 ruby
Total number of items: 48

So, as it is, just need it to print 1 ruby and 45 gold coin. It does the addition but prints 0 ruby and stays at 42 gold coin. If anyone has a better way to write this second function, I'd very much like to see it as I'm not at all content with this one.

Comment: I'm not sure why your `addToInventory` function accepts the `addedItems` argument but then immediately overwrites it with the global `dragonLoot` value.

Comment: Sorry I left it as I was trying to do something else with it, I'll post it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `displayInventory` function again looks up the current values directly in `stuff`, which is not the inventory that was previously updated.

I don't know why you are doing that, because you have that value in the loop, but then ignore it. You should be using that value.

```
for k, v in inventory.items():
    item_total = item_total + v
    print(v + ' ' + k)
```

Comment: Only had to pass str() to v on your code and it works. The end of the chapter projects are meant to draw on the stuff that was explained, so that's why it I had it that way. Because it worked before I got to the second part of the project, I didn't think the error was there.